# Last Section appearing on top with usage of pagestyle fancy

Tags: sectioning, xetex, fancyhdr, pagestyle

I am having trouble including page numbers in my resume. I earlier used 
`\pagestyle{empty}` for non-numbered page but thought to have page numbers. So I decided to use following packages which works for numbering. however, the last section in the pages, appearing on top. If I remove these packages, it works fine.

[Edit]: A Key thing to note is my sections are non-numbered for actual page display (as they should be) but on the top it appears with numbering.

Yes I am using `\fancyhdr{}` before `\cfoot`. I believe there is some incompatibility between packages, I am using since if I remove `\pagestyle{fancy}` and put `\pagestyle{empty}` it works as expected but of course pages will not be numbered.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}                   

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage{lastpage}
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2.5pt}{2.5pt}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{\hspace{0.25cm}}{0em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2.5pt}{2.5pt}


%\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\begin{document}


\section{One}
\section{Two}
\end{document}
```

Output
[image: Code Output]

Comment: Please show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) then we have not to guess what you are doing!

Comment: Apologies, I might have to add little big code since I believe it is about compatibility between packages.

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not sure I understand you right:

It seems you want to get rid of the printed section name in header with style `fancy` ...

Style `fancy` is predefined and adds the section name and an headrule to the headers. 
To get rid of them you need to redefine style `fancy` like this:

```
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} % <==========================================================
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % <==================================
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

With `\fancyhf{}` you delete all predefined things, with `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` you delete the headrule.

With the following complete mwe

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} % <==========================================================
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % <==================================
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2.5pt}{2.5pt}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{\hspace{0.25cm}}{0em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2.5pt}{2.5pt}


\begin{document}
\section{One}
\section{Two}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting page]